Wrapping `geepack::geeglm()` in a function does not play nice
I have the following R code:
library(geepack)
library(nlme)

data(dietox)
dietox$Cu     <- as.factor(dietox$Cu)
mf <- Weight ~ Cu  + Time

step1_func<- function(formula, data, id,family){

  # Step 1: Initial estimation using GEE with `geepack::geeglm`
  step1 <- geepack::geeglm(
    formula,
    family = family,
    data = data,
    id = id
  )

  return(step1)
}

step1_func(mf, data=dietox, id=Pig, family=poisson("identity"))


When I run this I get an error Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'id' not found.
That being said when I am working with geepack::geeglm() It works fine (albeit with some warnings).
# This works!
geepack::geeglm(
  mf,
  family = poisson("identity"),
  data = dietox,
  id = Pig
)

What is the issue here? Is there a fix that can make this work?

Note that geeglm uses NSE to carry out modelling. I will give a simple example. Below:
fn1 <- function(data, x)  get(substitute(x), data)
fn2 <- function(data, x) fn1(data, x)


fn1(head(iris), Species)
[1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

fn2(head(iris), Species)
Error in get(substitute(x), data) : object 'x' not found

Note that fn2 fails even though its just a wrapper of fn1.
A workaround. You could use do.call or as.call + eval etc. I would advice using as.call since the output includes the call to match.call:
step1_func<- function(formula, data, id,family){

  step1 <- as.call(list(quote(geepack::geeglm), 
               formula = formula, 
               family = substitute(family),
               data = substitute(data), id = substitute(id)))|>
           eval()

  return(step1)
}

